# How to send a message with a random @mention on Slack using BotKit?

Tags: javascript, bots, slack-api, slack, botkit

I'm new to developing bots and trying to use BotKit within Slack to mention a random user in the #test channel every week. Here is the code I have so far:

```
controller.hears('interactive', 'direct_message', function(bot, message) {
  // send webhooks

  bot.configureIncomingWebhook({url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/my/hook/uri'});
  bot.sendWebhook({
    text: 'Hey!',
    channel: '#test',
  },function(err,res) {
    // handle error
  });
});
```

Right now this sends a message "Hey!" to the #test channel when I direct message the bot "interactive", which is fine. How can I get all the usernames of users, and randomize them so that the text outputs like so: `text: '"Hey " + "@" + random.username + " !"',`. I would want this message to send every week as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Slack provides a `users.list` function as described here: [Slack API users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)

The `members` array contains `user` objects. You can user `user[0].name` to access the first username you want to @mention. in the demo they provide this would be @bobby.

Potential problems could arise because it returns the list in "no particular order"... you could potentially store it in a separate database and look to add elements if they are new and randomize based on your database entries.